# How to skip an rm command without erroring out of the script

Tags: script, rm

My SFTP script errors out if the target file in my "rm xxx" command doesn't exist.  Sample script:

```
OPEN sftp://pwd@host 
cd from_ar
rm file1.edi -f
rm file2.edi -f
rm file3.edi -f
rm file4.edi -f
cd ..
cd to_ar
Put -nopreservetime -nopermissions -transfer=ascii "D:\outfile1.edi"
Put -nopreservetime -nopermissions -transfer=ascii "D:\outfile2.edi"
Put -nopreservetime -nopermissions -transfer=ascii "D:\outfile3.edi"
Put -nopreservetime -nopermissions -transfer=ascii "D:\outfile4.edi"
Bye
```

If file2 doesn't exist, will adding a -f parameter to the end skip that file and go on with the rest of my script or will it stop the script without reporting the error?

Comment: To what are you connecting? Linux?

Comment: The script is running on a Windows server.  Not sure what the os is of the server we're connecting to, but I assume it is Windows as well.